# mysql collation different in php/mysql/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, collation

i am trying to add accent management in my request using the collation command, but i'am getting errors linked to invalid collation...

**this is my sql request :**

```
SELECT  p.ID,p.NOM,p1.ID,p1.NOM,p.ISNAV,p.LIEN
    FROM  p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  p AS p1 ON p.FK = p1.ID
    WHERE  (      p.NOM   LIKE '%dev%' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
              OR  p.HTML  LIKE '%dev%' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
              OR  p1.NOM  LIKE '%dev%' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
              OR  p1.HTML LIKE '%dev%' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
           )
      and  p1.TPL<>'search'
    ORDER BY  p.FK t
```

**this is my error in php:**

```
COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

**this is my error in mysql command line:**

```
COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

**this request works in phpmyadmin**

when i change utf8mb4_unicode_ci by utf8_unicode_ci in mysql console, the request works...but not in my php code.

i'am a bit lost, may someone explain me why i get collation error when my column seems to have the good collation.

Thanks

Comment: If you make those 4 columns `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, you won't need to specify the `collate` in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`mysqli::set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) in php.

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: thanks, i need 3min to validate the answer, by the way does that mean default php charset is latin1 (i don't have any charset configured in php.ini)  and default mysql charset is utf8 (i dont have any charset configured in my.conf)?

Comment: There are the bytes you have.  There is the connection between PHP and MySQL.  There is the `CHARACTER SET` on the table/column.  There is the output in html.  _All_ should be utf8; you can't trust the pieces to default correctly.